# Why is localStorage["..."] undefined, but localStorage.getItem("...") is null?

Tags: javascript, null, local-storage, undefined

Last time I checked, the following two lines returned `true`:

```
null == localStorage["foo"];
null == localStorage.getItem("foo");
```

Same applies when replacing `null` with `undefined`.
So the first question is, why are there two ways to address the localStorage? And why does

```
localStorage["foo"]
```

return `undefined` while

```
localStorage.getItem("foo")
```

returns `null`?

Do I need to take care of that when developing JS?

Comment: Ah, the joys of Javascript.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the language is fine, it's the implementation variations that kill it :(

Comment: Naturally, whether it returns `undefined` or `null`, you're going to still have to deal with it.  Why not just check for both?  See also http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/268125

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I'd do that if necessary, but I'd like to avoid needless overheads which is why questions like this bother me. If something undefined always returns `true` when checked agains `null`, why should I (additionally) check if it's undefined?

Comment: See muchweb's answer below.  Also, check the link I posted above; using `==` with `null` also checks for `undefined`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Web Storage Specification requires](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-storage-interface) that `.getItem()` returns `null` for an unknown key.

Note however that `.getItem()` and `.setItem()` are specifically defined in the IDL as being the designated `getter` and `setter` for the `Storage` interface, and therefore they're also fully supported ways of accessing the contents of the storage.

However the `[]` syntax is more akin to a normal object and/or array property getter, and like those returns `undefined` for an unknown property name.

The reason *not* to use `[]` syntax is that it will operate on object properties first and will quite happily allow you to overwrite real properties and methods of the `localStorage` object, c.f:

```
> localStorage['getItem'] = function() { return 0 }
> localStorage.getItem('getItem')
0
```

Comment: Does the last statement about overwriting "real" localStorage properties still apply? As of today, I was not able to reproduce this (in Firefox Developer Edition). Executing your code gives me `"function () { return 0 }"`.

Comment: @jaySon On current Chrome (51.0.2704.79) it still returns zero.

Comment: @jaySon and still the same with Chrome  55.0.2883.95

Comment: @jaySon and still with Chrome 68.0.3440.106

Answer (score 3):

`localStorage["..."]` is invalid usage of localstorage. You are trying to access methods of the `localstorage` object, rather than accessing actual database.

You have to use

```
localStorage.getItem("...")
```

and

```
localStorage.setItem("...")
```

methods to access storage database.

Comment: But you can "cross use" both syntaxes. Settings something using `setItem()` and getting it using `[]` works just as fine as the other way round.

Comment: indeed - on my Chrome (41?) the current keys all appear in `Object.keys(localStorage)`.  The `.getItem` is clearly safer, but it's hard to claim that the `[]` method is _invalid_.

Comment: @jaySon Using `localStorage['foo'] = 'bar';` shouldn't return an error but it's just creating an item in the localStorage object

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see a difference between items created with either syntax. They look and behave exacly equally so what do you mean by "it's _just_ creating an item"?

Comment: @vihan1086 that's plainly incorrect.  If I write `localStorage['foo'] = 'bar' then not only can I inspect that value in my debugger, but the `.length` property also changes, and _most importantly_ the value will persist in my browser!

Answer (score 2):

In javascript you always get an `undefined` value for keys that does not exist inside an object.

```
a = {}; //new object
alert(a["test"]); // you get 'undefined' because "test" keys is not found
```

In localStorage `.getItem` is a method who does check keys inside the localStorage object and returns `null` if not found.

Don't blame javascript, it's just the localStorage object behaviour

Comment: I came up with the exact same question today and your answer was for me the best understandable.