# localStorage retuning `undefined` on ReactJS and react-router-v4 code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, passport.js, react-router-v4

I´m bulding a simple router to build my authentication mechanism. The mechanism will use JWT stored in localStorage to know I´m authenticated. Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types"; 
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Redirect
} 

const isAuthenticated = () => {

    let token = localStorage.getItem("jwtToken");

    console.log('Local Storage JWT TOKEN:');
    console.log(token); // <<<<=== undefined

    if (token) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
};


const AuthenticatedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) =>

    <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
            isAuthenticated()
                ? <Component {...props} />
                : <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: "/landing",
                            state: { from: props.location }
                        }}
                    />}
    />;

class App extends Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/landing" component={Landing} />
                    <Route exact path="/logout" component={Logout} />
                    <Route exact path="/pagenotfound" component={PageNotFound} />
                    <AuthenticatedRoute exact path="/" component={AppNav} />
                    <AuthenticatedRoute
                        exact
                        path="/:option"
                        component={AppNav}
                    />

                    <Route component={PageNotFound} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

For some reason localStorage.getItem is returnin `undefined` if no token is found. I was expecting `null` here as expected [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)

Why is my `getItem` returning `undefined` and how to solve it?

Comment: are you calling `localStorage.setItem` from somewhere?

Comment: Tried a fiddle https://codepen.io/anon/pen/paqMxp  and it gives me null

Comment: Is this behavior same for different browsers?

Comment: @G_S, this is my point. It normally returns `null`, but inside my app this component is returning `undefined`

Comment: @ztadic91, please explain "somewhere"....

Comment: Whether the token is `null` or `undefined`, your check should work the same. What is the issue it is causing? Or are you saying it never gets set and you want to know why?

Comment: You can force `null` with: `let token = localStorage.getItem("jwtToken") || null;`. If it is `undefined`, it will convert it to `null`.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda.. No, this is not a question of testing for `undefined`. getItem must return null and if I´m getting `undefined` something is wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519452/why-is-localstorage-undefined-but-localstorage-getitem-is-null This makes me think that you have a key `jwtToken` and it's value is set to `undefined`. Can you open your DevTools and check if an item with the key `jwtToken` exists and is blank?

Comment: I understood as per the documentation, getItem should return null if it doesnt exist . Am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda Bingo. This is the problem!